# What possibilites one has concerning the version control of documents?

Tags: 2013, version-history, version

Within a standard SharePoint 2013 site I'm providing a little document management system. What I wanted to know is, what kind of possibilities one has concerning the version control of documents and how the version control in general works on SharePoint 2013 (in the very standard, no plugins, APIs etc.). Here I especially would like to know, if the document version is always counting linearly up (example: 0.1 -> 0.2 -> 0.3) when changing something or if there are also any other possibilities for users (for instance: 0.1 -> 0.2 -> 1.0 -> 1.1 ...) without using any additional scripts etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When versioning is enabled in site lists, you can track and manage information as it evolves. You can look at earlier versions and recover them, if necessary. That is very handy, for example, when people realize that earlier versions of an item might be more accurate than later ones. Some organizations retain multiple versions of items in their lists for legal reasons or audit purposes.

When you enable and configure versioning, you can retain versions each time an item it is edited. You need to decide how many versions you allow, and whether you want all site users to see all draft versions, or only be visible only to the originator and specific people in your organization.

By default, versioning is turned off. To turn it on and implement your versioning decisions, you must either have Full Control or Design permissions.

You might also want to track both major and minor versions of a file. A major version can signal that a document is ready for review by a wide audience, whereas the minor (draft) version is a work-in-progress and not yet ready for wide circulation.

you can get the detailed info regarding version from **Versioning Settings** of **List Settings** page and accessing the below link.

[image]

Here in your requirement you can make use of the option to how many number of major versions need to be maintained like 1.0 , 2.0 and if you need you can make use of draft versions like 1.1,1.2 likewise...

Comment: What if i need it to start from 0.1?